# django celery send multiple emails

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a view like"

```
def MyView(request):
    SendMyMail(args)
```

and my SendMymail is:

```
def SendMymail(args):
    send_mail(title, content, sender, receiver)
```

Here I want to queue the message sending process if there is so many messages. I have gone through document of celery and understood the base.

I have seen in many examples people are creating task.py file where they define the task with period. I want to know what to write in view then.

Can anyone give me clear example how can I accomplish of sending multiple emails

Comment: You don't write anything in the view - celery uses tasks, in your tasks.py file. The celery docs have everything you need.

Comment: should I use celery beat or celeryd to send hundreds of email. What exactly is difference between celeryd and celery beat

Comment: celeryd allows tasks to be run asynchronously, celerybeat allows tasks to be run periodically, like cron. You will always use celeryd, you can use celerybeat if desired, but you dont have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'll give you an example to get you going. Use celery to send a mail async.

```
def my_view(request):

    from tasks import celery_send_mail

    user = request.user
    <some_stuff>
    celery_send_mail.delay(user.email)
    <keep_going>
    return render(request)
```

then in tasks.py

```
@celery_app.task(ignore_result=True)
def celery_send_email(email):
    <send_your_mail>
```

To use celerybeat, you can set up the task to run periodically from your celery.conf file, or use a third party app to help, I use django-celery, as you can set the periodic tasks from the admin.

Comment: can you give me any example of periodic task.. I mean when to use periodic task and also when to use async task

Comment: the whole point of celery is to run tasks async - that is, they run orthogonally to the main thread, and thus don't interrupt it. Like my example above, the send mail will spawn another thread, and the main thread will keep on running. A periodic task would be one you want to run at a set time every day/week/month. Like updating a stock price for example.